# Swift: ViewDidLoad does not continue after having accepted notifications permissions request

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, microphone

I'm creating an iOS application in Swift and in the AppDelegate I insert the following code in the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** to ask the notifications permissions

```
    let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    // set the type as sound or badge
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
        guard granted else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
    }
```

Meanwhile, in the ViewDidLoad, I ask the user the microphone permissions in this way:

```
    func checkPermission()
{
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
    {
    case .authorized:
        print("ok2")
        self.addButton()
        self.voice()
    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, completionHandler: { granted in
            if granted {
                print("ok1")
                self.addButton()
                self.voice()
            else {
                print("ko")
            }
        })

    case .denied:
        print("ko")
    case .restricted:
        return
    }
}
```

The problem is:
After accepting the microphone permissions, I accept the notification permissions, but, after that, the code in the ViewController does not proceed (methods addButton and voice are not executed).

Could you help me?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Did you try to call `checkPermission()`in `viewWillAppear`or `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`? And are you experiencing the same issues here?

Comment: Will "ok1" be printed?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen yes, "ok1" is printed

Comment: if ok1 is printed then they should be called, did u debug it ?

Comment: @Teetz No, I did not try it. Maybe if I call the function in viewWillAppear, it will work. I will try it. thank you

Comment: if u write it in viewWillAppear it will be called every time the view Appears

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi true. i just wanted to know if he is experiencing the same issues then.

Comment: yes, i understand mate.

Comment: @Teetz i tried to call it in the viewWillAppear and it works.. thanks for the suggestion...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the problem is caused by threading issues: The completion handler in `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess` is executed in an arbitrary worker thread. If you do UI stuff here (like adding a button), this has to be done in the main thread, e.g.

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) { granted in
    if granted {
        print("ok1")
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.addButton()
            self.voice()
        }            
    else {
        print ("ko")
    }
}
```

But I wonder why UIKit does not crash (or at least complain) in your case.